# Putting shlex in debug mode

Tags: python, shlex

I wanted to see if [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) was a good choice for something I'm trying to build, so I thought I'd put it in [debug mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.shlex.debug) to play around with it. Only, shlex's constructor has this [weird thing it does](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shlex.py#l51): it sets `self.debug` to `0` and then immediately checks if it's true.

```
…
self.debug = 0
self.token = ''
self.filestack = deque()
self.source = None
if self.debug:
    print 'shlex: reading from %s, line %d' \
          % (self.instream, self.lineno)
```

I know Python has some powerful metaprogramming features, but I can't figure out how this is intended to work – even if I override the constructor, there's no programmatic way to get between the setting of the value and its use.

Is there supposed to be a way to output the statement in the `if self.debug` condition (and if so, how?), is it a bug, or is there some third possibility I haven't considered?

Comment: Programmatically surely there's a way: http://ideone.com/wcPVRg. But it looks like a really old code, [written in 1999](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2bdca80eb5d7757d4542e9e12e425a54a11fe300/Lib/shlex.py) something and no one has touched that part at all. o_O

Comment: Last one was bit hardcoded, here's slightly different way: http://ideone.com/lDCKvu

Comment: That seems like a bug. It is perfectly reasonable for `shlex` to require you to set `s.debug = 1` only after construction… but in that case, there's no good reason for it to check `self.debug` during the initializer.

Comment: That being said, it's not a _terrible_ bug. You're only missing that first message, which you can easily reproduce yourself, right?

Comment: @abarnert no, it's not a terrible bug. It's just baffling in a "surely I'm missing something obvious" kind of way.

Comment: @kojiro: IIRC, `shlex` was originally a standalone script; presumably when ESR was adding stuff to his script and merging it over to the not-quite-identical module he'd submitted to the stdlib, he didn't notice that this line didn't make sense once merged, and nobody else was paying attention. So, everyone involved missed something obvious. :)

Comment: @kojiro: Meanwhile, are you going to report the bug? Someone should; if you don't want to, I'll do it.

Comment: @abarnert eventually if no one else does, but not in the next few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm pretty sure you've found a bug, and you should [go report it](http://bugs.python.org). (You should make sure that it's still present in [the latest 3.x code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/shlex.py), but I just checked, and it is.) I don't see anything unreasonable about `shlex` objects not allowing you to set `debug=1` until after they're initialized… but in that case, they shouldn't be checking `self.debug` in the initializer, since there's no way it can be set.

But this isn't that hard of a bug to work around. The only thing you lose this way is the first message, which only prints out public attributes you can print yourself. So, for example:

```
class debugging_shlex(shlex):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # shlex is an old-style class in 2.7, so no super
        shlex.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.debug = 1
        print('shlex: reading from %s, line %d' \
              % (self.instream, self.lineno))
```

---

More information for the bug report:

- The unreachable code was added in [this 2000 change](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/81a121d21340), and the only change since then was to fit it to 80 columns.
- There are no unit tests for the `debug` argument (not surprising, given that it's barely documented and just says "if you want to use this, read the source"… but you might want to add some anyway).

Comment: Well, I'll open a bug, but [the list of unhandled open bug reports on `shlex`](http://bugs.python.org/issue?%40search_text=shlex&ignore=file%3Acontent&title=shlex&%40columns=title&id=&%40columns=id&stage=&creation=&creator=&activity=&%40columns=activity&%40sort=activity&actor=&nosy=&type=&components=&versions=&dependencies=&assignee=&keywords=&priority=&status=1&%40columns=status&resolution=&nosy_count=&message_count=&%40group=&%40pagesize=50&%40startwith=0&%40sortdir=on&%40queryname=&%40old-queryname=&%40action=search) doesn't give me much hope.

Comment: @kojiro: My guess is if you submit a patch removing those 2 lines, there's a greater than 50/50 chance it'll get accepted; if you don't submit a patch, nobody else will bother, and eventually it'll be another 47-month-old `shlex` bug that nobody cares about.